# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\arcsin(x) \sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

This is an exam problem from my analysis 1 course, and I can't find a way to solve it.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\arcsin(x) \sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}$$

So far I have tried applying L'Hopital's rule since, as x approaches zero, we get $\frac{0}{0}$ as a result. Eventually I got:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{\sin (x)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{\arcsin(x)\cos(x)}{2\sqrt{\sin(x)}}}{\frac{1-x}{\sqrt {2x-x^2}}}$$

Fast forward few steps, after trying to get rid of the double fractions, I got

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2x-x^2}(2\sin(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}\arcsin(x)\cos(x))}{2(1-x)(\sqrt{1-x^2})(\sqrt{\sin (x)})} $$

And I get again $\frac{0}{0}$ when I let x approach zero. I honestly doubt I should apply L'Hopital again here, and since I can't see any other way around I am asking for help or a clue how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By tg, do you mean tangent or some other function?

Comment: @NinadMunshi yes its tangent, or tan. I write tg since that is the notation we prefer at my faculty.

Comment: I asked because your derivative for tangent made little sense

Comment: The limit doesn't exist as $x\to 0.$ That's because for small $x<0,$ both $\sqrt {\sin x}, \sqrt {2x-x^2}$ are not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to keep multiplying and dividing by powers of $x$ like so

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\arcsin x \sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}} = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\cdot\sqrt{x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\arcsin x}{\sin(\arcsin x)}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2-x}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\cdot \sqrt{x} \to 1 \cdot 0 \cdot 1\cdot 0 = 0$$

by using the known limits (manipulating $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$) for each of the others. But the double-sided limit does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to do it that way, and btw. according to Symbolab, the double sided limit does exist and its exactly zero. (If we mean the same thing with 'double-sided)

Comment: @GrigoriPerelman that cannot be, $\sqrt{\sin x}$ does not exist immediately to the left of $0$ (it takes imaginary values)

Comment: I made several mistakes while rewriting some parts, I am fixing right now. Sorry for that

Comment: No worries it happens!

Comment: Ok i fixed it, there is no tangent in the actual problem. :)

Comment: @GrigoriPerelman I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I see, thanks once again. I just checked on wolfram alpha too, and it also says that the double sided limit is 0. (When x approaches 0 from both sides)

Comment: @GrigoriPerelman computer resources can be wrong. WolframAlpha especially has known weakness for limits. Use your own judgment, not a computer's. $\sqrt{\sin x}$ and $\sqrt{2x-x^2}$ do not exist immediately to the left for small negative numbers. If you had combined the square roots into one expression in your original question, then that would be different because it is not always true that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$

Comment: Warm congratulations for the last comment ! If I may ask : are you teaching ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici no unfortunately not :/ Why do you ask?

Comment: Then, in this case, you would be a fantastic one ! From the time you joined MSE, I use to follow your answers; they are so good, so clear. I would have liked to have you as a teacher. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you! That is the best compliment I could get from a fellow mathematician

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\tan(x) = x + O(x^3)$$
$$\sin(x) = x + O(x^3)$$
$$\arcsin(x) = x + O(x^3)$$

Now it should be easy calculated. Sometimes it's easier to use Taylor expansion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am still not familiar with the O notation thing. I was hoping to find a solution using the more basic ways.